# How can I terminate my build if certain preconditions are not met?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I would like to do something like the following in my GNU makefile:

```
ifndef TOP
  abort Error TOP not defined
endif
```

Is there a way to terminate with a simple message to the terminal if all the required variables are not defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(error Error TOP not defined)`

From http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Make-Control-Functions:

```
$(error text...)
Generates a fatal error where the message is text. Note that the error is generated whenever this function is evaluated. So, if you put it inside a recipe or on the right side of a recursive variable assignment, it won't be evaluated until later. The text will be expanded before the error is generated.
For example,

          ifdef ERROR1
          $(error error is $(ERROR1))
          endif
will generate a fatal error during the read of the makefile if the make variable ERROR1 is defined. Or,

          ERR = $(error found an error!)

          .PHONY: err
          err: ; $(ERR)
will generate a fatal error while make is running, if the err target is invoked.
```